# GWT UiBinder margin

Tags: gwt, margin, uibinder

I have UiBinder exmaple od FlexTable with child elements.

I have a problem, because browsers creates a few px of margin all around child elements in Flextable and around this tabel too. I cannot get rid of this margin - it is impossible to delete it with Firebug or with properties in CSS or style.

What am I doing wrong?

best

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the style of the FlexTable (and child elements) using CSS:

```
<ui:style>
  .myTable td {
    border-spacing: 0;
  }
</ui:style>
<g:HTMLPanel>
  <g:FlexTable styleName="{style.myTable}" />
</g:HTMLPanel>
```

[More information here](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html#Hello_Stylish_World)